# How can I make a jquery accordion menu with clickable top level links?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, accordion

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery/

Works great. I want to use this for my site's category based navigation. Categories have subcategories and I have lots of categories so an accordion menu is perfect for having lots without the site looking cluttered with 100 category links.

Using the linked online demo above as an example, if someone clicks the golden background for "Sports" or "Technology" or "Latest", I want it to behave normally and expand the accordion menu. If they click the text for "Sports" or "Technology" or "Latest", I want to have it work like a normal link and send them to a new page. As far as I can tell, I can only find examples where the text and the background expand but none with a separation of functionality.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below. It will make the text inside the heading be a link but the div is still clickable to expand.

Replace

```
<div>Sports</div>
```

With

```
<div><a href='http://google.com/'>Sports</a></div>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UnV4Z/

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but now how can I make, say, Golf be an accordion itself and go 3 deep instead of just 2?

Comment: That's a separate question but you can make it work by just nesting `ul` elements and modifying the css and javascript a little bit.

Comment: Thanks, I posted here and got it partially working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920458/how-can-i-use-nested-accordion-menus-without-multiple-instances