# How can I use nested accordion menus without multiple instances?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

Here's my base:

http://jsfiddle.net/UnV4Z/

And I want it to be three levels instead of just two. I've got it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RnwYQ/13/

But it means that I've got to have one instance per category. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the accordion a class and slightly modifying the code to make it hide siblings based on clicked element.

http://jsfiddle.net/RnwYQ/19/

```
$(".accordion > li > div").click(function() {

    if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).parent().siblings().children("ul").slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
}).parent().filter(":first-child").children("div").click();​
```

Comment: This nests properly but now the items that are links don't work.

Comment: They should be working, i'm not doing anything to prevent them. However, note that they aren't working in your code either.

Comment: @Citizen jsfiddle is preventing them. If you add target="_blank" to the markup for those links, it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/RnwYQ/18/

Comment: Debug says that that's invalid javascript. Is that the case?

Comment: says that what is invalid javascript

Comment: Copy and past gave invalid token error, but it was a bad character due to copy and paste, everything works, thanks!